# Twilio Messaging Service with test credentials

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Using Twilio test credentials allows simulation of sending SMS messages from/to valid numbers, non-SMS-capable numbers, invalid numbers, etc., by using specific numbers for the value of the 'From'/'To' parameter of the HTTP POST to Twilio.

Is there any way to use Twilio test credentials to simulate sending (successfully or unsuccessfully) using a value for the 'MessagingServiceSid' parameter instead of a value for the 'From' parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The [test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#supported-resources) page says: "All of the existing outbound SMS parameters will work, with the exception of MessagingServiceSid." so it doesn't sound like it is currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid the [test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#supported-resources) only work for the following endpoints:

- Buying phone numbers: POST `/2010-04-01/Accounts/{TestAccountSid}/IncomingPhoneNumbers`
- Sending SMS messages: POST `/2010-04-01/Accounts/{TestAccountSid}/Messages`
- Making calls: POST `/2010-04-01/Accounts/{TestAccountSid}/Calls`

Comment: Right, but when posting to `.../{AccountSid}/Messages`, you can normally supply either a `From` or a `MessagingServiceSid` field.  If you're using test credentials, there are various test numbers that you can supply in the `From` field to elicit various responses.  The question was whether there are any analogous values that you can put in the `MessageingServiceSid` field.

Comment: Bah, you're right I read your question wrong. I will test this and get back to you.